# How to make the first Char Upper in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I need to know how i can make a string like `"hello"` to `"Hello"` using PHP? 
I just need the first character to be Upper

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use the function `ucwords()`; This will do every word in the string, using `ucfirst()` will just do the first word.

```
echo ucwords('hello my name is jim');

// Hello My Name Is Jim

echo ucfirst('hello my name is jim');

// Hello my name is jim
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know this one! +1.

Answer (score 6):

You need the [`ucfirst`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) function.

> Returns a string with the first character of str capitalized, if that character is alphabetic.

It will not make the other characters lowercase. To make sure only the first letter is upper case and rest all are lowercase you can do:

```
ucfirst(strtolower($str))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [ucfirst()](http://www.php.net/ucfirst)

See the list of [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php), it will answer most of your string related questions.

Answer (score 1):

For: first char of string

Use: ucfirst("first char of string"); //output First char of string

For: all first char of word in string

Use: ucwords("all first char of word in string") // output All First Char Of Word In String